# how i will make text in "menu" in javafx using css

Tags: css, javafx

In that picture, I want to make "file" "edit" "view" bold. I am new to JavaFX please tell me in detail. I am using scene builder but in that, it is not there. thanks in advance

[image: image here]

Comment: sorry picture is not uploading normal "menu bar text" only.

Comment: <Menu text="File">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Close"/>
            </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu text="Help">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="About"/>
            </items>
        </Menu>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
.menu-bar .menu .label {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Since you say you're new to JavaFX:

- [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#menubar)

  - A helpful resource for looking up the CSS structures of various JavaFX Nodes
- [Scene Builder CSS Properties/Analyzer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/stylesheet-support.htm)

  - Oracle documentation on using Scene Builder's CSS features. Hasn't been, and might never be, updated for JavaFX 9.
  - While Oracle no longer maintains Scene Builder I believe the documentation should be helpful.